# Why one to one bidirectional association doesn't have unique index in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm beginner in Symfony and Doctrine. I'm reading Doctrine associations, and **I don't undertand why**:

**One-to-one unidirectional associations have a unique index in the foreign key, but one-to-one bidirectional associations don't have this unique index**.

Here's the MySQL schema's example in Doctrine documentation that will be generated in the OneToOne unidirectional association:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    shipping_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_6FBC94267FE4B2B (shipping_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Shipping (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Product ADD FOREIGN KEY (shipping_id) REFERENCES Shipping(id);
```

And here's the script for bidirectional association:

```
CREATE TABLE Cart (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE Cart ADD FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(id);
```

Is there something that I understood wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it? Maybe a simple typo in the docs.

Comment: @PatrikKarisch you are right, is a typo of docs. Thanks!